# SplitView Controller Can't Pass From Master to Detail

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I am trying to convert my iPad app from using a Tab Bar Controller as its Root View to using a Split View Controller for it.  My code in my AppDelegate.h is:

```
@class RootViewiPad;
@class WebViewController2;
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate> {
UIWindow *window;


UISplitViewController *splitViewController;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISplitViewController *splitViewController;
@end
```

The .m is:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "WebViewController2.h"
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize splitViewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    



    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];



return YES;
}
```

I use IB to set all this up, and I Added a SplitViewController in the MainWindow, and connected the AppDelegate Connection for SplitViewController to the SplitViewController I added.  Under the Navigation Controller in the SplitViewController I set the root view to RootViewiPad (The TableView that parses a blog and shows the articles), and then set the other View Controller Class and NIB to WebViewController2 which is where I would like the articles to display once they are clicked on.  When I run the app, it compiles, and I can see the WebViewController2 that I built in IB, and when I rotate, the left hand side is the TableView I created.  However, I can't figure out how to get it to load the URL in the WebViewController2.  Everything I have tried either does nothing, or merely pushes it on the Master Side of the controller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    WebViewController2 *detailViewController = 
    self.webViewController2;

    detailViewController.webView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
    RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [detailViewController.webView loadHTMLString:entry.articleImage baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:nil]];  

}


}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `NSLog(@"Controller: %@, View: %@", detailViewController, detailViewController.webView);` just before the `loadHTMLString:` line and see what it says these objects are.

Comment: @PhillipMills returned both (null)

Comment: OK, that leads to the obvious question: how do you think `self.webViewController2` is getting initialized?

Comment: @PhillipMills  I honestly do not know.  This is my first time doing a Split View Controller so I'm open to guidance here.  Do I need to add something to my AppDelegate code I listed, or do I need to do something different in my Root View iPad code listed?

Comment: It depends (doesn't it always...).  Are you using a storyboard?  If not, what xib files are in your project?  (If it's an older style project with MainWindow.xib as the place where you're making your connections, it's easy, just control-drag from the outlet named `webViewController2` in your master controller to the detail controller itself.)

Comment: @PhillipMills That did it!  I had to add an IBOutlet into the property for it, but then I was able to hook-up the connection and it works great now!  All that's left is just setting up Popover and I'll have it!  Thank you very much!